# Trouble installing hstats library from hackage using cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage

When I try to install the `hstats` package

```
$ cabal install hstats
```

I get the following error:

```
src/Math/Statistics.hs:1:1:
    Ambiguous module name `Prelude':
      it was found in multiple packages: base haskell98-2.0.0.2
Failed to install hstats-0.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hstats-0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hstats depends on `base >= 2.0` **and** `haskell98`. The current version of `base` contains the `Prelude` module, which was part of `haskell98` at the time `base` was still in version 2.x, but Prelude is now part of the base package.

You need to unpack `hstats` and fix the error by yourself. Basically, exchange

```
build-depends:       base>=2.0, haskell98
```

with

```
build-depends:       base>=4.0
```

in hstats.cabal:

```
$ cabal unpack hstats
$ cd hstats-0.3
$ vim hstats.cabal
$ cabal install .
```

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the archive http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hstats-0.3/hstats-0.3.tar.gz , removed haskell98 as a dependency, and did `cabal install`. Works!

Comment: Why is this not fixed officially?